# How to upload code for Blynk app to nodemcu using Arduino?

Tags: nodemcu, arduino-esp8266

i am trying to make an anti theft door notification IOT app. I am using nodemcu,arduino for coding and a blynk app to operate it. I have already installed a drivers from the link for nodemcu. Now I don't why I am not able to upload a code.

I am getting this as an error:
Sketch uses 281080 bytes (26%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1044464 bytes.
Global variables use 30152 bytes (36%) of dynamic memory, leaving 51768 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 81920 bytes.

error: Failed to open COM1
error: espcomm_open failed
error: espcomm_upload_mem failed
error: espcomm_upload_mem failed

Answer (score 0):

You are getting

```
error: Failed to open COM1 error: espcomm_open failed error: espcomm_upload_mem failed error: espcomm_upload_mem failed
```

Because the arduino IDE was not able to upload code to the nodeMCU through COM1.
There are multiple reasons for this to happen,

1. If you are on linux or mac, make sure you have write permission to the port. (as the port you mention looks like a windows port this is probably not your issue.)
2. Make sure that you have selected proper board in the Arduino IDE board list.
3. Press and hold the flash on nodeMCU and plug the USB cable into the PC, once you connect the cable release the flash button. now try to upload the code.

Comment: Yes. I was missing 2nd point that you have mentioned here and also its particular drivers. Thanks.